EventSource Error: ERROR: Exception during EventCounter cpu-usage metricProvider callback: Attempted to divide by zero
I was trying to debug using visual studio. It does opened a new tab on my browser but nothing came up (I saw that it was still loading). On output window in visual studio:
EventSource Error: ERROR: Exception during EventCounter cpu-usage metricProvider callback: Attempted to divide by zero.
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (13472) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

This went about several times (when memory usage is not as high, it only shows the thread destroyed). Then the debug stopped prematurely and at the end of the output window was:
EventSource Error: Reached message limit.   End of EventSource error messages.
The program '[9144] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

When I check the new tab, it shows an error
HTTP Error 500.37 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start within startup time limit

As a side note, my memory was on 96%. I tried to lower it but it showed the same result.

EDIT:
I've tried:

reinstalling the visual studio
lower the memory until about 60%
changing port of IIS Express App Url

I got one instance of it working but dunno what makes it work, and later it doesn't work again.
The project indeed works on other computers.

Since you don't encounter this situation when debugging on other computers, I would suggest trying to upgrade your Visual Studio and ASP.NET Core versions on your computer to see if that resolves the problem. Or, you can compare the differences in the environments between the two computers to identify potential causes.

This suddenly cropped up for me on a project that was working fine. The call stack doesn't show any of my code, and I am not sure why this method is even being called. It seems that you can ignore it, but it is frustrating when trying to debug the app.  Did anyone find a fix?

@NebulaSleuth I still haven't found any solution to this. I opted to using Visual Studio Code instead with Run -> Start Debugging. It's working fine there.

Also got this error. Seems to be an issue with the Diagnostic Tools.
I got rid of error messages by unchecking the .NET Counters in the Diagnostic Tools panel settings. Can't say why it's doing it but that will hopefully at least remove the errors.
